# Finding minimum number in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

As a noob i am trying to find the min number from an array.

```js
function findLowest(number) {
  for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    const index = i;
    const element = number[i];
    let lowest = element;


    if (element < lowest) {
      lowest = element;
    }
  }
  return lowest;
}

height = [10, 16, 25, 2];
result = findLowest(height);
console.log(result);
```

The error message is:

> ReferenceError: lowest is not defined

Please explain the error message.

Comment: You'll need to declare the `let lowest` *outside of* the loop, and initialise it *before* the loop.

Comment: what may have confused you is that this would have worked had `let lowest = element` been `var lowest`.

Comment: You need a lastknownLowest and return lastknownLowest when loop is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    function findLowest(number) {
        let lowest =  number[0];
        for (let i = 1; i < number.length; i++) {
            let element = number[i];
            if (element < lowest) {
                lowest = element;
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }

    height = [10, 16, 25, 2];
    result = findLowest(height);
    console.log(result);
```

your code snippet problems:

1. `const index = i;` is not used and please remove it.
2. please don't use `const` for `element` because it isn't a constant number and `let` is better there
3. what is minimum number? a number that is minimum among all numbers... so for first step, assume first element is minimum and run a for loop from second element to last and if an element is less than your assume, choose that.

```
lowest =  number[0];
```

and

```
if (element < lowest) {
    lowest = element;
}
```

4. `let lowest = element;` this line is harmful and it replace lowest with element in every step and so you missed minimum in a step which the element is not lower...

Comment: Your solution assigns a global variable

Comment: @Bergi did you mean it's a bad way? if yes, I will be grateful if if edit it... because you're very professional, I haven't anything to say :( and I'll learn

Comment: I meant you forgot the `let` keyword on the `lowest` initialisation in your runnable snippet that I'm sure you intended to be there :-)

Answer (score 0):

You define `lowest` inside the for loop. You can't access it outside the loop. Take a look at this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to use `Math.min`:

```js
console.log(Math.min(...[10, 16, 25, 2]));
```

Comment: you're right, but your code is not good for a person who want to learn about `loop`s and `js` fundamentals

Comment: The question is: `Finding minimum number in an array in javascript`, not `Finding minimum number in an array in javascript with a loop`. Also, `Math` functions are js basics.

Answer (score 0):

It's a scoping issue. On [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#description):

> `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited to the scope of a block statement, or expression on which it is used

You're re-declaring `lowest` in the for/loop block but `return` cannot see it.

If you initialise `lowest` with the first element of the array first you can minimise the amount of code you write in the loop. I would also add a condition to check whether the input is an array, and has length, so you can short-circuit the function if the condition isn't met.

(And you should ensure that you declare all of your other variables properly with `let` or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).)

```js
function findLowest(arr) {

  // Check that the input is an array,
  // and that it is not empty
  if (!Array.isArray(arr) || !arr.length) {
    return 'Invalid input';
  }

  // Initialise `lowest` with the
  // first array element so it has a value
  let lowest = arr[0];

  // If the current element < `lowest`
  // update `lowest`
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < lowest) {
      lowest = arr[i];
    }
  }

  return lowest;

}

const arr1 = [10, 100, 6, 2, 16, 25];
const result1 = findLowest(arr1);

console.log(result1);

const arr2 = [];
const result2 = findLowest(arr2);

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimum Number from an array

```
let arr=[10, 16, 25, 50];
console.log(Math.min(...arr));
```

Minimum Number from a multiple array

```
let arr1=[10, 16, 25, 50];
let arr2=[1, 15, 20, 21];
console.log(Math.min(...arr1,...arr2));
```